# how to add a property to an object?

Tags: javascript

Given an object that has a "firstName" property and a "lastName" property, "addFullNameProperty" returns a "fullName" property whose value is a string with the first name and last name separated by a space.

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'Jade',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
addFullNameProperty(person);
console.log(person.fullName); // --> 'Jade Smith'
```

my code :

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  obj[fullName] = obj.firstName + obj.lastName;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-object-properties/

Answer (score 1):

Either use `obj.fullName` or `obj['fullName']`

But a more correct solution would be

```js
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'fullName', {
    get:  function(){
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
          }, 
    configurable:false
  });
}

var person = {
  firstName: 'Jade',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};

addFullNameProperty(person);

console.log(person.fullName); // --> 'Jade Smith'

person.firstName = "Mike";

console.log(person.fullName); // --> 'Mike Smith'
```

This way your object will always return the correct `fullName`.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple set:

```
obj.fullName instead of  obj[fullName]
```

Or

```
obj['fullName']
```

Because fullName in your code is undefined variable. So JS alert error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the space into the name, you will need to do *string interpolation*, like so:

```
`${obj.firstName} ${obj.lastName}`
```

and complement this with Gaby's answer about switching to *dot notation*, obj.fullName

Answer (score 0):

Add new property to an existing object:

```
const person = {
  firstName: 'Jade',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};

person.fullName = `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
```

same as:

```
person['fullName'] = `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
```

or using method:

```
const person = {
    firstName: 'Jade',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    fullName(){ 
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
};
```

`person.fullName(); // Jade Smith`

You can also use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

return obj.fullName = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName